# Insert multiple checkbox value with textbox value in database

Tags: php, mysql

```
   <b>
   <li>
    <img height="150" width="200"src="<?php echo $images_dir."/tb_".$row[2]; ?>"/>
     <input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='<?php echo basename($images_dir."/".$row[2]);?>'/><input type='text' name='textbox[]'id='textbox'/>    </br>
```

This code shows some images with checkbox and textbox. I want to select one or more  image and give them text value and store in database. Here is the code is for inserting

```
  $checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];

   $txt=$_POST['textbox'];

   if($_POST["submit"]=="submit") {
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++) {
   if(!empty($txt)) {
  echo""
  $query="INSERT INTO message(item,quantity)       VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$txt[$i]."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  }
 echo "message is send";
 }
 ?>
```

When i run this code then it inserts only checkbox value but textbox value is not   inserted in database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

textbox[ ] is a array. So Use `$txt[$i]`

```
$query="INSERT INTO message(item,quantity)  
 VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$txt[$i]."')";
                                      ^
```

Your Complete code with only **one textBox**

```
<b>
   <li>
    <img height="150" width="200"src="<?php echo $images_dir."/tb_".$row[2]; ?>"/>
     <input type='checkbox' name='chk1[]' value ='<?php echo basename($images_dir."/".$row[2]);?>'/><input type='text' name='textbox'id='textbox'/>    </br>


 $checkbox1=$_POST['chk1'];

   $txt=$_POST['textbox'];

   if($_POST["submit"]=="submit") {
   for($i=0;$i<sizeof($checkbox1);$i++) {
   if(!empty($txt)) {
  echo""
  $query="INSERT INTO message(item,quantity)       VALUES('".$checkbox1[$i]."','".$txt."')";
    mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  }
  }
 echo "message is send";
 }
```

Comment: this code store one selected value with text but i am select two checkbox it can not store 2nd textbox value but checkbox value is sotred

Comment: if you want only one textbox value then why are you taking array for textbox..just use simple name without array

Comment: i want to say that multiple checkbox value with multiple textbox value insert in database

Comment: textbox value is same for all checkbox or different?

Comment: textbox value is same

Comment: text box value is same