# php how to modify insert based on series of checkboxes

Tags: php

I have a form who asks for a series of check boxes...

```
<? while( $tag2 = mysql_fetch_array($tag))
{ ?>
 <td><? echo $tag2['tag'];?><input type="checkbox" name="check[]" value="<? echo $tag2['tag_id'];?>"></td>
    <? } ?>
```

how do I treat the sql to insert in DB with the check box array. So far, I have this, but can't figure out how to account for the different checkboxes:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   if(!empty($_POST['check']))
 {
     foreach($_POST['check'] as $check)

     {
            // DONT KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE
     }
}

 $sql = mysql_query("insert into ..... ");
```

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear..  the sql is this : $sql = mysql_query("insert into blogtag_ref (tag_id, blog_id) VALUES ('".$check."', '".$blog_id."')"); ...  how do I treat the $check  to get the right value for each

Comment: See this answer on SO, might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825982/

Answer (score 0):

Since '$_POST['check'] is already an array, you could simply implode them into a string that can be used by your query.

I'm not sure how you are trying to store them in the database, but if you are storing the data in a single column, you could do something like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
    $sql_string = implode(', ', $_POST['check']);
}

$sql = mysql_query("insert into table set field = '".$sql_string."'");
```

If you are storing them one for each row, you could do something like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['check'])) {
    $sql_string = implode('\'), (\'', $_POST['check']);
}

$sql = mysql_query("insert into table (field) VALUES ('".$sql_string."')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// the question you asking is incomplete.

foreach($_POST['check'] as $check)
{
    $sql[] = $check;
}

//which do nothing you can be just after checking/filtering and do this
$sql = $_POST['check'];

//and you probably need the following
$sqlCommaSeperated = implode($sql,",");
```